# Why is my Binary search program in python not working correctly?

Tags: python, binary-search

```
# Binary search in python
def BinarySearch(A,n,x):
    start = n - 1
    end = 0
    while start <= end:
        mid = (start + end)//2
        if x == A[mid]:
            return mid
        elif x < A[mid]:
            end = mid - 1
        else:
            start = mid + 1
    return -1


A = [4, 5, 7, 45, 64, 66, 80, 81, 92, 99]
n = len(A)
x = 64
result = BinarySearch(A,n,x)
if result != -1:
    print(result)
else:
    print("element is not in the array")
```

output : element is not in the array
whatever element I am providing to this code it's always giving the same output

Comment: You have `start` set to the _end_ of your list, and `end` set to the _start_ of your list.

Answer (score 0):

Swap start and end variable values:

```py
    start = 0
    end = n-1
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have assigned wrong values to start and end as per algo.

```
start = 0
end = n - 1
```

Put these values and it runs.

[image: PoW]